# Negative lookaround-- regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to learn regular expressions on my own, hence this silly activity.

I am trying to retrieve any word with "football" in it, but exclude "footballs" from that--so I can get anything else--footballer, footballers, football. Just not "footballs".

I found that `\bfootball(?!s)\b` gets rid of both footballers and footballs. How do I only exclude "footballs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must move word boundary inside the assertion:

```
/\bfootball(?!s\b)/
```

That is more correct than remove the word boundary at all.
When you remove the boundary at all, you miss the words with `s` and something after it:
`footballsa` for example.

Answer (score 1):

`\bfootball(?!s)\b` is excluding "footballers" because you are looking for a word boundary, then "football", then not a S, then another word boundary (which doesn't allow you to find anything after "football"). Get rid of the end word boundary (in other words, use `\bfootball(?!s\b)` instead).

Comment: No, it is not; `footballsa` for example

Comment: Then use `\bfootball(?!s\b)` instead. The point is you don't want the word boundary to always come right after "football".

Comment: @Palladium: I know that, I've already wrote that in my solution before I added this remark; I just wanted to note that your original solution was incorrect.